# sql if statement not working

Tags: sql, if-statement

I can't get this if statement to work. 
I'm trying to say 'if(number of dates) is greater than 330, return 'x', otherwise give me the (number of dates)

```
SELECT     if(ROUND(COUNT(ClosedDate) / 10, 0) * 10 > 330 then 'X' else ROUND(COUNT(ClosedDate) / 10, 0) * 10) end AS [Previous Day Sales]
FROM         PartsSales
WHERE     (MONTH(ClosedDate) = MONTH(GETDATE())) 
AND       (YEAR(ClosedDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())) 
AND       (DAY(ClosedDate) = DAY(GETDATE() - 13))
```

Comment: doesn't have to be an 'x' either - can be an integer if necessary, as long as it's static beyond 330

Comment: That's hard on the eye. Please surround that in `code tags` with better formatting.

Comment: Is the query even running? Becuase you will need to use `case..when`

Comment: Come on format the code.  You have 4 questions.

Comment: Which dbms do you use?

Comment: You have to set the same datatype in then and else

Comment: *can't get this if statement to work* Do you get any error?

Answer (score 0):

Use a CASE clause:

```
SELECT     CASE WHEN ROUND(COUNT(ClosedDate) / 10, 0) * 10 > 330 then 'X' else ROUND(COUNT(ClosedDate) / 10, 0) * 10 end AS [Previous Day Sales]
FROM         PartsSales
WHERE     (MONTH(ClosedDate) = MONTH(GETDATE())) AND (YEAR(ClosedDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())) AND (DAY(ClosedDate) = DAY(GETDATE() - 13))
```

Comment: this works perfectly. So damn grateful. thank you thank you thank you

Comment: Great, glad to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please could you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN ROUND(COUNT(ClosedDate) / 10, 0) * 10 > 330
THEN 'X' ELSE ROUND(COUNT(ClosedDate) / 10, 0) * 10) END AS [Previous Day Sales]
FROM PartsSales
WHERE MONTH(ClosedDate) = MONTH(GETDATE())
AND YEAR(ClosedDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())
AND DAY(ClosedDate) = DAY(GETDATE() - 13)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) >= 335 THEN 'X'
             ELSE CAST(ROUND(COUNT(ClosedDate) / 10, 0) * 10) as VARCHAR(255))
        END) AS [Previous Day Sales]
FROM PartsSales ps
WHERE CAST(ClosedDate as DATE) = CAST(DATEADD(day, -13, GETDATE()) as DATE);
```

Notes:

- You `WHERE` clause is too complicated.
- Why is the "previous day" using the day from 13 days ago?
- Be explicit about the types!  You are mixing strings and numbers.  The result of the `case` expression needs to be a string.